# echo the sql-command after sql-send-region

Tags: terminal-emacs, sql-mode, postgresql

Currently I can select a region and call `sql-send-region`, it can be executed well. But if the command needs a long time to run, I am not sure if the command was send or not until the command is completed.

so do we have a method to show the command I send with 'sql-send-region' before it is run?

thanks